# Cual es la diferencia entre Spring/JSF/JSP?

Tags: java, jsf, jsp, spring

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y quisiera saber cales son las principales diferencias o que me recomiendan que aprenda?

Answer (score 5):

JSP:

- Era el framework para la generación de páginas web anterior a que se definiera JSF.
- Se basa en generar un fichero .jsp que es "traducido" a una clase `Servlet` que a su vez es compilada y ejecutada.
- Hay dos versiones: con scriptlets (`<% %>`) que se considera obsoleta, o con la Java Standard Template Library (JSTL). La última implementa el MVC, mientras que con la primera normalmente todo el código va en el propio JSP.

JSF:

- Es un framework para la generación de páginas web dentro de una aplicación web. Sigue la filosofía MVC.
- Tiene dos "modos": usando JSP o Facelets. Inicialmente se usaban JSPs, pero a partir de la versión 1.2 por defecto se usan Facelets (componentes XML). Normalmente se confunde "JSF" por "Facelets" (si buscas "componentes JSF" encontrarás librerías de Facelets).
- Estandariza cuestiones como navegación entre páginas y la internacionalización de recursos que en JSP simplemente no estaban definidas.

Spring:

- Es un stack alternativo a Java EE. Como tal, proporciona una serie de servicios similares a los del stack (por ejemplo autenticación y seguridad, ORM/acceso a datasources, etc.).
- No reemplaza completamente el stack; por ejemplo es muy común integrar una capa web JSP o JSF con una base Spring, o usar componentes del stack (como la API de Validation) dentro de Spring o viceversa (usar Hibernate en vez de JPA dentro de una aplicación Java EE).

Answer (score 4):

**JSF**

- Es un sistema que facilita el desarrollo de la interfaz de usuario en páginas web.
- Dispone de varias características de base, por ejemplo dos librerías de etiquetas `<xml>`.
- Es un framework.
- Soporta conversión a `validator`, `ajax` etc...
- Puedes integrar JSF con ricas librerías para diferentes interfaces de usuario.

**JSP**

- Es un lenguaje basado totalmente en `Java` para hacer páginas web dinámicas.
- Tiene que ser compilado en Java bytecode.
- No es un framework.

Si como has dicho estás empezando te recomiendo usar JSF dado que es mas sencillo de manejar, pero si vas a hacer páginas mas complejas yo tiraria por JSP

Comment: muchas gracias por tu explicaciones! y Spring en este caso como seria?, haber si entiendo osea que con JSF puedo agregarle independienteme cualquier estilo css? por ejemplo Bootstrap? @Alberto Martienez

Comment: @GiorgioMagaña si, a JSF le puedes agregar bootstrap. Sobre spring, no hay mucha diferencia con JSF dado que solo cambia algunas terminologias, así que parecido al JSF

Comment: "Sobre spring, no hay mucha diferencia con JSF dado que solo cambia algunas terminologias, así que parecido al JSF" totalmente incorrecto. Comenzar con que Spring es todo un ecosistema basado en Spring Core. Luego, Spring MVC es un framework web Java mvc basado en acciones, mientras que JSF es un mvc basado en componentes.